# Android.SQLite.БД. Не работает update

Tags: android

Не работает метод `update`, все остальные работают... не знаю в чём дело. Никакой ошибки не появляется, просто он не заменяет данные.
Вот метод

```
 public int updateButton(MyButton myButton) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER, myButton.getNumber());
    values.put(COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH, myButton.getWidth());



    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(myButton.getID()) });
}
```

**Settings.class**

```
  public class SettingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
boolean isEmpty=false;
private SQL_Helper mDatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;
int number;
float width;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);





    Button okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_setting, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onOkButtonClick(View view) {

    SQL_Helper sql_helper = new SQL_Helper(this);

    EditText buttonNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ButtonNumber);
    EditText buttonWidth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ButtonWidth);

    if ((buttonNumber.getText().toString().equals("")) || (buttonWidth.getText().toString().equals("")))
    {
        isEmpty=true;
    }
    else isEmpty=false;

    if (isEmpty) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Вы ввели не все данные!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }
    else{
        number = Integer.parseInt(buttonNumber.getText().toString());
        width=Float.parseFloat(buttonWidth.getText().toString());

        if ((number<0) || (number>100) || (width>1) || (width)<0 ){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Некорректный ввод!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        else

        if (sql_helper.isEmpty(number))
        {
            sql_helper.addButton(new MyButton(number, width));

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Данные добавлены в базу!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }

        else {

            sql_helper.updateButton(new MyButton(number,width));
                    String str = "Данные этой кнопки изменены! "
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),str
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }



}

public void onBackButtonClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(SettingActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onDeleteClick(View view) {
    SQL_Helper sql_helper = new SQL_Helper(this);
    sql_helper.deleteAll();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Все данные удалены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
}
 MyButton.class

    public class MyButton {
    private int _id;
    private int mNumber;
    private float mWidth;
    public MyButton() {

    }
    public MyButton(int id, int number , float width){
        this._id=id;
        this.mNumber=number;
        this.mWidth=width;

    }
    public MyButton(int number , float width){

        this.mNumber=number;
        this.mWidth=width;

    }
    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.mNumber;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.mNumber = number;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
        return this.mWidth;
    }

    public void setWidth(float width) {
        this.mWidth = width;
    }

}
```

Comment: Может button не возвращает данные?

Comment: @JoeSilent 
Проверял,возвращает

Answer (score 1):

Вы везде используете конструктор без параметра id:

```
new MyButton(number,width)
```

А для update используете именно id, который никогда не задаете. Он всегда == 0

```
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(myButton.getID()) });
```

Вообще, странная конструкция - класс с названием `MyButton`, который не наследуется от `View`, и является по сути не кнопкой, а моделью.

Comment: id у меня автоматически инкрементируется при добавлении данных в таблицу,  myButton.getID() правильно возвращает id , не в этом дело.
MyButton просто класс с гетерами ,сетерами, для удобства

Comment: @Mihailenko, у вас: `sql_helper.updateButton(new MyButton(number,width));` Каким образом, используя эту конструкцию,он поймет, запись с каким ID обновлять? Вы же ему не указывете.